# GUI update works in IDE but not always from jar file

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, user-interface

I develop using Eclipse IDE on a Mac running OSX 10.7.5. This program constructs an array of JPanels, when the user clicks a panel all the other panels on the same row or column change color, blue for left mouse button, red for right button. When I run from the IDE everything works fine, at least I've never seen it fail. But when I create a .jar file and run by double clicking that, most of the time it works fine but every once in a while it doesn't change the color of some of the other panels.

To test I pick one square and alternately right click and left click it. As I said most of the time it works and all the other panels in the same row or the same column change color. But if I right click a square and some of the panels stay blue that's the failure. If I right click the same square again it doesn't change the display; the failed panels stay blue. It's like the manager thinks everything is the right color and doesn't bother to update the display.

If I resize the panel or click any other square with either button, all panels flip to the correct color. This code doesn't have an explicit call to repaint() but I've tried that and it doesn't fix the problem. I've tried reading about repaint manager, but haven't found a way to get the display to reliably update. As I said, I've never seen this happen when running the IDE and most of the time it works as an application too. Just now it took about 50 clicks to get a failure.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class GUITest extends JPanel {

    final static int NROWS = 81;
    final static int TOTAL_SQ = NROWS * NROWS;
    Square[] square = new Square[TOTAL_SQ];

    public GUITest() {
        setLayout(new GridLayout(NROWS, NROWS));
        for (int i = 0; i < TOTAL_SQ; i++) {
            square[i] = new Square(i);
            add(square[i]);
        }

    }

    public void squareClicked(int id, int button) {
        // determine which row and column
        int row = id / NROWS;
        int col = id % NROWS;
        // change background color of all squares on same row or column
        for (int i = 0; i < TOTAL_SQ; i++) {
            if ((row == i / NROWS) || (col == i % NROWS))
                if (button == MouseEvent.BUTTON3)
                    square[i].setBackground(Color.RED);
                else
                    square[i].setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        }
    } // squareClicked

    class Square extends JPanel implements MouseListener {
        int id = 0; // which square this is

        public Square(int id) {
            this.id = id;
            setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
            addMouseListener(this);
        } // Square constructor

        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        }

        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        }

        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
        }

        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        }

        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
            squareClicked(id, e.getButton());
        }
    } // Square

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("GUI Test");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        GUITest app = new GUITest();
        frame.setSize(800, 600);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.getContentPane().add(app, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

I have a second question that might be related. IDE displays much faster than the application does. The IDE updates in a flash. The application updates each panel individually, it's noticeably slower. I guess that the IDE is using a double buffered display. I read about that too, but don't see how to make it hold off updating until the entire display is ready.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1) Wall-of-Text alert!  Use paragraphs.  2) *"I have a second question that might be related."*  That entire slew of words contains no '?' so ..what was your ***first*** question?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any problems with your logic and I can't duplicate your problem when I run the code from the command line using JDK7 on Windows 7.

However, when I run the code I do get an exception when the frame loads:

```
C:\Java>java GUITest
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comparison method violates its general contract!
        at java.util.TimSort.mergeLo(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.TimSort.mergeAt(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.TimSort.mergeCollapse(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.TimSort.sort(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.TimSort.sort(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.Arrays.sort(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.Collections.sort(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.SortingFocusTraversalPolicy.enumerateAndSortCycle(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.SortingFocusTraversalPolicy.getFocusTraversalCycle(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.SortingFocusTraversalPolicy.getFirstComponent(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.LayoutFocusTraversalPolicy.getFirstComponent(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.SortingFocusTraversalPolicy.getDefaultComponent(Unknown Source)
```

The first thing I tried was to make sure all the code is executed on the EDT:

```
EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
{
    public void run()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("GUI Test");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        GUITest app = new GUITest();
        frame.getContentPane().add(app, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setSize(800,600);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
});
```

I still got the exception. So I then tried changing the code to reduce the number of components being displayed on a single panel:

```
setLayout( new GridLayout(NROWS,1) );
int squares = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < NROWS; i++)
{
    JPanel panel = new JPanel( new GridLayout(1, NROWS) );

    for (int j = 0; j < NROWS; j++)
    {
        square[squares] = new Square(squares);
        panel.add( square[squares] );
        squares++;
    }

    add( panel );
}
```

I no longer get the exception. Don't know if this will help or not.

Also, Swing is double buffered by default, so I'm not sure why each component is updated individually. Swing should combine repaint requests for individual components so they are done at one time, but maybe only groups of components are being repainted.

The only way around this is to not use components and instead create your own component that does custom painting of each rectangle. Of course this will be more involved because you would also need to do your own "hit detection" to determine which rectangle was clicked.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I hadn't gotten the exception before. I decided to open a terminal window and run from there to see if I got it. I didn't so that's still a question. But I also didn't get the failure, at least not so far, and the display updates very quickly. I'm thinking maybe it's a setting in the JVM, since the only time I see it is when I double click the jar file in mac finder. What's different in double-clicking the file vs running from a terminal window? I don't know.